# How to get the value of a macro with a string containing the macro name?

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to get the value of a macro with a string containing the name of the #define? Or is it impossible to access a macro through its name after compiling the code?

To point out what I'm after:

```
#define NAME "VALUE"
char string[5];

// I want the content of string to be changeable to access any define
strncpy(string, "NAME", 4);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", string);
```

I want to have the output: *VALUE*

**EDIT**
Due to MOHAMED's reply I found this solution:

```
#define NAME "VALUE"
char string[5];

strncpy(string, "NAME", 4);

if(strncmp(string, "NAME", 4) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", NAME);
}
```

Comment: macro's operate solely on text replacement

Comment: Sure: `strncpy(string, NAME, 4);`

Comment: @H2CO3 Not so sure: string has only room for 5 chars and copying only 4 results in "VALU"...

Comment: @Jens Right, that should be `char str[6]; strcpy(str, NAME);`... (`strncpy()` is **not** safe anyway...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the macro name directly

```
strncpy(string, NAME, 4);
```

You can not edit the content of the string defined by the macro

the macro is evaluated in the compilation phase. the compilator generate a second code (called preprocessor code). this code is generated by the compilator in which the compilator replace the macro by its content.

so if your first code is

```
#define NAME "VALUE"
char string[5];

strncpy(string, NAME, 4);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", string);
```

the code generated by the compilator will be

```
char string[5];

strncpy(string, "VALUE", 4);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", string);
```

you can see the preprocessor code with:

```
gcc -E file.c
```

Comment: See the added program comment

Comment: You can not edit the content of the string defined by the macro. answer updated

Comment: What is the point of copying 4 characters when "VALUE" is longer?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.  Macros are replaced by their replacement text during the preprocessing phase, before the C compiler itself sees the code.